# How to refactor string containing variable names into booleans?

Tags: spss

I have an SPSS variable containing lines like:

```
|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|
```

Every line starts with pipe, and ends with one. I need to refactor it into boolean variables as the following:

```
var       var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
|2|4|5|   0     1     0     1     1
```

I have tried to do it with a loop like:

```
loop # = 1 to 72.
compute var# = SUBSTR(var,2#,1).
end loop.
exe.
```

My code won't work with 2 or more digits long numbers and also it won't place the values into their respective variables, so I've tried nest the `char.substr(var,char.rindex(var,'|') + 1)` into another loop with no luck because it still won't allow me to recognize the variable number.

How can I do it?

Comment: split by pipe and cyle resulted array .. you must be more specific. give us a piece of code where you tried something ..

Comment: I have tried it with for loop, but sadly I can't do it with substring.

Comment: post your loop to see where you miss something ..

Comment: http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-variable-types-and-formats/    did you know : "SPSS has two variable types: string and numeric. Numeric variables may contain only numbers. String variables may contain letters, numbers and other characters. The distinction between numeric and string variables is important because the variable type dictates what you can or cannot do with a variable."

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am not accustomed to SPSS yet, so I corrected the sample.

Comment: What language did you use? on what environment !?

Comment: I am using SPSS' built-in syntax editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a nice job for the `DO REPEAT` command. However the type conversion is somewhat tricky:

```
DO REPEAT var#i=var1 TO var72
         /i=1 TO 72.
COMPUTE var#i = CHAR.INDEX(var,CONCAT("|",LTRIM(STRING(i,F2.0)),"|"))>0).
END REPEAT.
```

**Explanation:** Let's go from the inside to the outside:

- `STRING(value,F2.0)` converts the numeric values into a string of two digits (with a leading white space where the number consist of just one digit), e.g. 2 -> " 2".
- `LTRIM()` removes the leading whitespaces, e.g. " 2" -> "2".
- `CONCAT()` concatenates strings. In the above code it adds the "|" before and after the number, e.g. "2" -> "|2|"
- `CHAR.INDEX(stringvar,searchstring)` returns the position at which the searchstring was found. It returns 0 if the searchstring wasn't found.
- `CHAR.INDEX(stringvar,searchstring)>0` returns a boolean value indicating if the searchstring was found or not.

Comment: Uh Oh my original answer had a glitch. Given var="|3|12|", the ouput would be var1=1, var2=1, var3=1, and var12=1, because "1" and "2" are included in "12". I have now corrected my answer so that the search string is not the number itself, but the number enclosed by "|".

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do the manipulations in Python than native SPSS syntax.

You can use `SPSSINC TRANS` extension for this purpose.

```
/* Example data*/.
data list free / TextStr (a99).
begin data.
"|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|"
end data.

/* defining function to achieve task */.
begin program.
def runTask(x):
    numbers=map(int,filter(None,[i.strip() for i in x.lstrip('|').split("|")]))
    answer=[1 if i in numbers else 0 for i in xrange(1,max(numbers)+1)]
    return answer
end program.

/* Run job*/.
spssinc trans result = V1 to V30  type=0 /formula "runTask(TextStr)". 
exe.
```